# GA event goal tracking onSubmit not tracking in GA because of race condition

Tags: javascript, html, forms, analytics, onsubmit

Google Events are not being registered when my form is being submitted.

Here's the form tag:

```
<form action="https://xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.com/app/form/process/e3315c4ac3527afdf3da8b6b8b84209f" method="post" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'HCompany', 'HomePage', 'OptIn']);"
```

I'm pretty sure it's because the new page is loaded before the event is registered.

Can someone suggest how this can be modified to delay the submit until the event is registered?

Answer (score 0):

(I found the answer to my own question.) A delay can be added using the settimeout() function. I added this new javascript function to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delaysubmit(category, action, label) {

try {
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action, label]);
} catch(err){}

setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
}, 100);
}
</script>
```

And then I modified the form tag as follows:

```
<form id="frm1" action="https://xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.com/app/form/process/e3315c4ac3527afdf3da8b6b8b84209f" method="post" onsubmit="delaysubmit('HCompany', 'HomePage', 'OptIn']); return false;">
```